# SQL WHERE statement not working 100%

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to return values where **Worldwide** = **yes** or where **visible** = **yes** and in **State** = **Florida** but this is not returning all the other values where the **Worldwide** is **yes**

```
select  * from Table1
where (visible = 'yes' and State = 'Florida') or Worldwide= 'yes'
order by ID DESC
```

**Edit: My BAD**

Sorry guys/girls, this statement does work! I had Select TOP 8 * in my statement that is why it did not return all the records! When I took the TOP 8 out it worked! My bad!

Comment: Do a SELECT DISTINCT Worldwide from Table1 to make sure that there aren't other values.

Comment: You can probably add some sample records which are not getting fetched but you are expecting them in output.

Comment: The column worldwide have the value yes or the value no

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your where clause and I doubt very much SQL Server would evaluate this wrong so as nonnb suggests, the "error" could be in the data.

Comment: what does `select count(1) where  Worldwide= 'yes'` return?

Comment: Show simple example data where you get it wrong and what you expect. For me that should do what you write.

Comment: Sorry guys/girls, this statement does work! I had Select TOP 8 * in my statement that is why it did not return all the records! When I took the TOP 8 out it worked! My stupidity sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Using following script, the query outputs what is expected.

**Create data**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
  ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , State VARCHAR(32)
  , Visible VARCHAR(32)
  , WorldWide VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 'Florida', 'Yes', 'Yes'  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Florida', 'Yes', 'No'  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Florida', 'No', 'Yes'  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Florida', 'No', 'No'  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Other State', 'Yes', 'Yes'  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Other State', 'Yes', 'No'  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Other State', 'No', 'Yes'  
UNION ALL SELECT 'Other State', 'No', 'No'
```

**Select**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @Table1
WHERE   (Visible = 'Yes' AND State = 'Florida') OR WorldWide = 'Yes'
```

**Output**

```
ID  State           Visible WorldWide
1   Florida          Yes    Yes
2   Florida          Yes    No
3   Florida          No     Yes
5   Other State      Yes    Yes
7   Other State      No     Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
where State = 'Florida' AND (visible = 'yes' or Worldwide= 'yes')
```

The other variant which covers all possible cases with syntax:

```
where UPPER([State]) LIKE '%FLORIDA%' AND 
((UPPER(visible) LIKE '%YES%') OR (UPPER(Worldwide) LIKE '%YES%'))
```

Comment: Strange. Check comments to your question. It might be an answer there. Moreover is char types Case Sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some nulls in there which may cause you some trouble.

```
select  * from Table1
where (IsNull(visible,'') = 'yes' and IsNull(State,'') = 'Florida') 
or IsNull(Worldwide,'')= 'yes'
order by ID DESC
```

Also check that the collation isn't case sensitive.  Collation can be set at Server, Database or Column level so you will need to check the following:

**Server Collation**

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
```

**Database Collation**

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DATABASENAME', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

**Column Collation**

```
Select table_name, column_name, collation_name
From information_schema.columns
Where table_name = @table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You have up to 4 issues

- case sensitivity
- spaces
- NULLs
- unexpected data

Variations which can be combined

```
--case
(LOWER(visible) = 'yes' and LOWER(State) = 'Florida') or LOWER(Worldwide) = 'yes'

--spaces
(RTRIM(LTRIM(visible)) = 'yes' and RTRIM(LTRIM(State)) = 'Florida') or RTRIM(LTRIM(Worldwide)) = 'yes'

--nulls
(visible = 'yes' and State = 'Florida') or ISNULL(Worldwide, 'yes') = 'yes'

--unexpected data: need samples
```